# ffmpeg armv7s compile segmentation fault

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, ffmpeg

I use https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script to compile ffmpeg, 
but when i try to compile, for armv7s architecture i have next error

all other archs compile fine

> clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11 clang:
>   error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see
>   invocation) Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM
>   3.6.0svn) Target: arm-apple-darwin14.3.0 Thread model: posix clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to
>   http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash
>   backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script. clang:
>   note: diagnostic msg:
>
> ---
>
> PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT: Preprocessed
>   source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at: clang: note:
>   diagnostic msg:
>   /var/folders/zk/wj2cn08s26x64nlzk3_kjnv80000gn/T/vp8-c6ec27.c clang:
>   note: diagnostic msg:
>   /var/folders/zk/wj2cn08s26x64nlzk3_kjnv80000gn/T/vp8-c6ec27.sh clang:
>   note: diagnostic msg:
>
> ******************** make: *** [libavcodec/vp8.o] Error 254 make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... CC  libavcodec/wmv2enc.o

Couple months ago all compiled without any errors.
Tried on couple versions of ffmpeg

Here is Clang -v

> Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 Thread model: posix

and xcode version is Version 6.3.1 (6D1002)

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution, as you can understand from this  article http://www.cocoanetics.com/2014/10/xcode-6-drops-armv7s/ xcode doesn't have armv7s support for now, so armv7s will use armv7 version and it must not reduce performance.